# Is there a way in VSTS using which I can see all the open pull requests across all the projects?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I would like to view all open pull requests across all of the projects under my VSTS account. Is there any plugin or any other way to do this?

I checked out this plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanstedman.tfs-pullrequest-dashboard&targetId=75aae682-e2e0-4f61-875b-c3b0544f2d4e&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList#overview but it only shows open pull requests for a particular project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t the built-in feature or extension can see all open pull requests directly, also, I don’t find the third-party extension can do it.

I recommend that you can build the app or extension through [Pull Request REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#get-a-list-of-pull-requests-in-the-account), you can refer to that extension’s source code to do it with an extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible by visiting `https://dev.azure.com/YOURACCOUNTNAME/_pulls`

Comment: This shows all of the user's open pull requests, but on all PRs in total.  Useful for tracking your own work but not so much for tracking the state of the overall project.